# Waiting on form return vb.net

Tags: vb.net, show, showdialog

What is the proper way to call up a form and wait until it recieves a replay before moving onto the next code step?

Example code is:

```
Public isLogedIn As Boolean = False

Private Sub Reprint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles  ReprintButton.Click
If isLogedIn = False Then
        Using lf As New frmLogin()
            lf.ShowDialog()
.....
```

Now lf is the login form that waits for the users password and then, depending on if its correct or not when they hit OK it should send back a true or false (isLogedIn).

Currently i do not know how to have the code wait until it receives something from the login form before moving onto the next code.

If i use my old code here:

```
 Do Until isLogedIn = True
    isLogedIn = isLogedIn
    intX = intX + 1
 Loop
```

It never ends if the user puts in a false login password so it just keeps waiting....

Any help would be great!

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use return type of ShowDialog() method - [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx). In Login form you have to set [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx) property of Buttons. For more info take a look at - [Dialog Boxes in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2chz8edb.aspx) and [Essential Code for Windows Forms Dialog Boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289504%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).